# How to turning back the situation when button clicked again in Qt?

Tags: qt

Basically I created QListWidget and QPushButton and I want to list current item in the widget when I clicked the button.Until here it is fine. What I want is after clicking that button again, I want to see previous situation(old item!) of that item. How can I do that?

```
    Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ){
        ui->listWidget->addItem(QString::number(i) + " old item!");
    }
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QListWidgetItem *itm = ui->listWidget->currentItem();
    itm->setText("new item!");       
}
```

Comment: You have to remember the old text and set it again afterwards by yourself.

Comment: What chehrlic posted will work, but if you want a more elaborate answer, use QListView instead of QListWidgetItem, and QStringListModel. You can store (or retrieve) the index of the original selection in the pushbutton slot. This approach is a little more work, but will give you more power and flexibility in the long run.